# Simultaneous CSS transition on link and its child span

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to have a css transition take place on a link upon hover. The text of the link should change color as well as a child span's color. It's happening except the span transition appears to start only when the first transition completed. Any ideas?

```
<div class="transition">
    <a href="#">
       Click here
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play pull-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>

.transition a,
.transition span        {
  -webkit-transition:color .2s linear;
  -moz-transition: color .2s linear;
  -o-transition: color .2s linear;
  transition: color .2s linear;
}
```

I tried separating the classes into two which made no difference.

**EXAMPLE**: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u2wavc67/)

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/ucwd2a31/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/obfhn9ot/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transition will cause the color to change for its children, so they will begin the transition again and again. Try to not transition inside a transition with the same property. If you want the color of the span to change with the parent, use `color: inherit;` without transition on the span.

Answer (score 1):

Just a fiddle as an example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cv820gma/)

```
.transition a       {
-webkit-transition:color .2s linear;
-moz-transition: color .2s linear;
-o-transition: color .2s linear;
transition: color .2s linear;
}
```